# How to deal with local packages freezing my IDE during workspace build

Tags: eclipse, node.js, npm, gulp, zend-studio

I have a question about local packages and gulp using them. The problem is, I have a packages.json in my working directory of my IDE with a lot of dependencies which also have dependencies. Now that wouldnt be much of a problem, but when I install them through npm, I get the directory node_modules.

The problem is that I have to build often but since the modules are getting installed in my local directory, my IDE starts to scan them and build the workspace. It hangs every time probably due to the complex dependencies. Apparently I need those packages locally because the gulpfile require('')s them.

I wonder if anyone else has stumbled upon this problem and what their strategy was for excluding the dependencies of their workspace. Eclipse (or in fact Zend Studio which I use, derived from it) doesn't seem to have its own exclude for it.

PS: I tried copying all to my global directory (where all packages are installed with the --global flag set) but there are that many dependencies within depedencies that the path becomes too long for Windows to handle (yeah I know, Windows). That didn't became a suitable solution either.

Comment: you can remove the build automatically option in eclipse...only build whenever you require it

Comment: That's not really a solution, as a PHP developer I'm pretty much relying on building my workspace for syntax errors and code completion. I can't be switching it off and on all the time if I am developing my application.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to big Node.js projects in Eclipse issue https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/159

The solution would be disabling JSDT nature for there project (see [Nodeclipse not recognizing generator functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213915/nodeclipse-not-recognizing-generator-functions) answer)

See http://www.nodeclipse.org/history